# Is it possible to give each record a differant css class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, class

Is there any way to give each record in a table its own css class? Im displaying records as partials but would like to be able to give each partial its own individual css attributes. Maybe a way of assigning css rules by a div's name and id of the record combined?

**EDIT**

Sorry for the poorly written question I'll try and explain in more detail.

I have a table of venue records being displayed on the index page in partials and want each one to have an icon placed on a map off to the left side of the screen (map_container). The map is just a hand drawn image as the background of a fixed width and height div.

Venue index.html.erb:

```
<div class="map_container">
</div>

<div class="filter_options_container">
  <form class="filter_form", method="get">    
    <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset">
      <legend class="filter_form_fieldset_legend">Choose an area:</legend>
      <% Area.all.each do |a| %>
        <span class="filter_form_checkbox_label">
          <%= check_box_tag("areas[]", a.id, false, :class => "styled")%>
          <%= a.name %><br>
        </span>
      <% end %>        
      <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="venue_partials_container">
  <%= render :partial => 'venue', :collection => @venues %>
  <div class="clearall"></div>

  <%= will_paginate @venues %>

  <div class="venue_partial_button">
    <%= link_to 'add a new venue', new_venue_path %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearall"></div>
```

I was thinking a way of doing this could be to make another table of icon records where one venue belongs to one icon and one icon belong to one venue. Then yielding the map div area to partials of the icon records. The differant css classes could then be something like:

```
.icon(with_venue_id_1) {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
}

.icon(with_venue_id_2) {
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
left: 20px;
}
```

etc etc....

Which I know is so horrifically bad it may bring a bit of sick in your mouth but my zero experience of programming ever has led me to this. I imagine theres so many better ways of doing it but this could work as a learning aid for me at least.

I would eventually like these icons and their positioning to be added from the running app itself but for now I'm happy just to get something working.

Thanks for any help, its much appreciated.

Comment: Question is not clear, if you want to generate the classes dynamically, how are you planing to style each class, what is the name format of classes. You need to put more effort in your questions to get answers.

Comment: @Hussein Thanks for the pointer I've improved on my question, hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<% @record.each do |r| %>
  <tr class="<%= r.id %>"> 
  <!-- Or some other value from the record? --> 
  ...
```

Not sure I understood the question completley.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll have a play round with it and get back with how its going. I have improved my question sorry that it was so vague.